# case_when breaks in multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have sample dataframe having ID against `Var` and lagged variable of var `LagVar`.

```
sd <- read.table(header = T, text = "ID Var LagVar
A 1 NA
A 2 1
A 4 2
A 6 4
")
```

I am checking if LagVar is same as Var or (Var -1). It is returning FALSE against last 2 rows.

I want Flag to set FALSE for first 2 rows and TRUE for last 2 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the order of statements and also the general property of `%in%` which does check for all the values in the column or the created vector with `c` and thus returns all `TRUE` as these values in 'LagVar' are present in 'Var' columns

```
library(dplyr)
sd %>%
     mutate(Flag = ((LagVar %in% c(Var, Var - 1)) | (Var == 1)))
```

-output

```
ID Var LagVar Flag
1 P2   1     NA TRUE
2 P2   2      1 TRUE
3 P2   4      2 TRUE
4 P2   6      4 TRUE
```

returns all `TRUE`, thus it checks on that alone instead of going into next ones

If we use a simple example

```
v1 <- 1:5
case_when(v1 <= 5 ~ FALSE, TRUE ~ TRUE)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The first condition returns all `TRUE`, thus it wouldn't execute the next condition.  The `~` is assigning the value based on the condition and not the condition itself.  If we want to execute the next condition, the first one should return FALSE and not by assignment

```
case_when(v1 > 5~  FALSE, TRUE ~ TRUE)
[[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

There is a confusion among the actual condition and the return value as both are logical

---

When we do the `%in%`, it checks all the rows unless grouped.  We could add `rowwise` attribute to prevent the check for all the rows

```
sd %>% 
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(Flag = !(LagVar %in% c(Var, Var-1)|(Var == 1))) %>%
    ungroup
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  ID      Var LagVar Flag 
  <chr> <int>  <int> <lgl>
1 P2        1     NA FALSE
2 P2        2      1 FALSE
3 P2        4      2 TRUE 
4 P2        6      4 TRUE
```

Or we may need to add one more condition with `==` and `|` as `==` does elementwise comparison

```
sd %>%
    mutate(Flag = !(LagVar == Var| LagVar == (Var - 1)|(Var == 1)))
ID Var LagVar  Flag
1 P2   1     NA FALSE
2 P2   2      1 FALSE
3 P2   4      2  TRUE
4 P2   6      4  TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you. I want Flag to set FALSE for first 2 rows and TRUE for last 2 rows. For example : LagVar= 2 and Var=4,  (2 %in% c(4, 4 - 1)) | (4 == 1)

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari how is the 2nd row FALSE 1 is present in c(var, var-1)`

Comment: Whenever this condition meets it should return FALSE else TRUE

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari please note that `%in%` is not elementwise, so all the rows in lagVar should be TRUE or FALSE depending on your condition

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari when you say Var -1, does it mean literally subtracting or the one value that should be preceding

Comment: I want rowwise comparison. Can't think of how to solve it. My bad, I complicated in the code. For example, second row contains Var = 2, Var-1 means 1

Comment: Thanks a ton. this is very helpful. "When we do the %in%, it checks all the rows unless grouped." - If I use groupby(ID) before mutate, shouldn't `%in%` works?

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari that wouldn't still work because there are multiple rows per group, and you want to do this for every row

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari or you want `sd %>% mutate(Flag = !(LagVar == Var| LagVar == (Var - 1)|(Var == 1)))`